# group items in lists python

Tags: python, list, grouping

I am working on a project and it involves a lot of manipulating lists. I'm trying to group objects in the list together, e.g the list:

```
["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P"]
```

would become:

```
["ABCD","EFGH","IJKL","MNOP"]
```

But I cannnot seem to find a way to do this. Please help?

Comment: Why are the groups 4 characters long?

Comment: What's the way to group your elements?...simply by four?

Comment: Yes, i only wish to group them in furs but i dont know how :/

Comment: Use the strategies in the marked duplicate, and then use `str.join()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone i have done it now ^-^